# I am trying to convert dynamic string into list but it is giving me escape sequences. How can I eliminate those sequences?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Exactly, what I am trying to do is implement TOP command through python to get particular columns of it. So, after p1.communicate(), it gives me data in tuple form. So, i converted it into string format to get data into list. When I am trying to decode it through decode(), it is still showing me escape sequences. I have also tried regular expression, replace() but it's not working.

Please help me with where I am going wrong.

Till now, I have tried this.

```
process=subprocess.Popen(['top', '-n', '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout=process.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
stdout=stdout.splitlines()
```

Comment: Could you share the output that you get as a tuple? BTW, you can convert a tuple to a list directly.
`tup1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)`
`lst1 = list(tup1)`
`print(lst1)`
`# [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

> When I am trying to decode it through decode(), it is still showing me escape sequences.

Of course it is - it's not `decode()`'s business to remove escape sequences. If you don't want them, just don't let `top` generate them; use the option for this:

```
   -b  :Batch-mode operation
        Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to
        other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs
        until the iterations limit you've set with the `-n' command-line option or
        until killed.
```

Granted the manual does not explicitly mention that this leaves out screen control sequences.

E. g.:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['top', '-bn1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```